# Phase shift of an ideal op-amp integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, bode-plot, integrator

I derived the transfer function of an ideal op-amp integrator and calculated the phase response of the Bode plot. My own derivation matches the result of [this website](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/integrator-limitations-the-op-amp-gain-bandwidth-product/).

This means for the transfer function and the magnitude response:

[image]

For the phase response I arrive at the same as the mentioned site, namely:

[image]

So this is exactly what I was expecting from my own derivation - namely that the phase is +π/2 or +90°.

But a lot of textbooks note that integrators have -90° phase shift although they note the same transfer function. I miss the reasoning behind that. Some people argue like: "the op-amp is in inverted configuration", others don't even argue but only state -90° without further explanation. I would say that especially *because* of the inverted configuration, we have that minus in the transfer function as denoted above and because of that a positive phase shift in total (+180° by the minus sign and -j=-90° are in total +90°).

What is the reason or the argumentation why the above derivation and the result of +90° phase shift is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What is the reason or the argumentation why the above derivation and
> the result of +90° phase shift should be wrong?*

It's not wrong...

The integration components around the op-amp subtract 90° but, the op-amp configuration is basically inverting so, 90° is subtracted from -180° to yield a net phase angle of -270° or +90°.

In other words, it's an inverting integrator: -

[image]

Comment: Are you now saying that this circuit indeed has a +90 degrees of phase shift and phase plots that show that circuit with -90 are essentially wrong because they don’t account for the inversion of the opamp?

Comment: The op-amp integrator produces an output phase angle that leads the input @Junius

Answer (score 2):

Integrating sin x gives -cos x

Cos x leads sin x by 90 degrees and so -cos x lags sin x by 90 degrees.

So the integration process itself produces a 90 degree lagging output but the op amp based integrator is configured in an inverting configuration and so the overall output leads the input by 90 degrees.